# Trying to calculate distance between two lat-lng points in PostgreSQL - what is the unit of PostgreSQL earth_box(ll_to_earth) return value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, distance, geography, earthdistance

I have a query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM chat_rooms 
WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth(5, 5), 111000) @> ll_to_earth(lat, lng);
```

Essentially, I have `lat = lng = 5` in the query, and in my `chat_rooms` table I have two entries, one with `lat=lng=5`, the other with `lat=lng=4`. Using an online calculator, the distance between these two entries is 157 miles = 252.667km (i.e. entry `lat=lng=4` should be returned when radius >= 157 miles. However, the query only returns the entry with `lat=lng=4` when the radius is specified as ~111,000+. My question is, what unit is the radius in, and am I conducting this query correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/earthdistance.html), by default, the radius is expressed in meters.

The most important flaw is that the distance between 4;4 and 5;5 is 157 km, not miles. Even though, 111,000m is not the same as 157,000m, but the doc for `earth_box` says

> Some points in this box are further than the specified great circle
>   distance from the location, so a second check using earth_distance
>   should be included in the query.

so your query should be similar to

```
SELECT * FROM chat_rooms 
WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth(5, 5), 111000) @> ll_to_earth(lat, lng)
AND earth_distance(ll_to_earth(5,5), ll_to_earth(lat, lng)) <= 111000
```

in which case entry at 5;5 won't be returned, but will be if you use 158000 instead.